# Is there an issue using event overloading and event logs that contain arrays?

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-design, remix, events

My event fires, but the last parameter is never logged. It appears as if it doesn't even exist. Here is my solidity code:

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.6;

contract EventTest {
  event marketCreated(address[] virtualShareAddresses, address market, uint256 indexed endTime, string description, string extraInfo);//categorical
  event marketCreated(address[2] virtualShareAddresses, address market, uint256 indexed endTime, string description, string extraInfo);//binary
  event marketCreated(address[2] virtualShareAddresses, address market, uint256 indexed endTime, string description, string extraInfo, int256 _minPrice, int256 _maxPrice, uint256 _numTicks);//scalar


  function createYesNoMarket(
    uint256 _endTime,
    string memory _description,
    string memory _extraInfo
    ) public payable returns (bool) 

  {
    address[2] memory virtualShareAddresses;
    address newMarket = address(0);
    virtualShareAddresses[0] = address(1);
    virtualShareAddresses[1] = address(2);
    emit marketCreated(virtualShareAddresses, address(newMarket), _endTime, _description, _extraInfo);
    return true;
  }
}
```

here's how I'm calling the event with web3.js:

```
contract.methods.createYesNoMarket(1575158400, "Will it rain on Friday in Sacramento California?", "foo").send({from: '0x5680CA2e3b4F8bC043aCeB31837c89DbA8bFBa75', gas: 6000000}, (error, hash) => {
  console.log(hash)
  console.log(error)
})
```

and here's my event.returnValues logged to the console:

```
{ '0': 
   [ '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
     '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002' ],
  '1': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '2': BigNumber { _hex: '0x5de30280' },
  '3': 'Will it rain on Friday in Sacramento California?',
  endTime: BigNumber { _hex: '0x5de30280' },
  virtualShareAddresses: 
   [ '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
     '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002' ],
  market: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  description: 'Will it rain on Friday in Sacramento California?' }
```

As you can see the extraInfo field is never logged. Anyone know why this is?

Comment: Use `indexed` for each important parameter. You can use it at most 3 times per event declaration, so choose wisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using event log overloading *and* arrays in the event log.

From superficial testing, I found it works as expected if you drop either of those features.

If you comment out the logs that aren't actually used in this test then things improve.

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.6;

contract EventTest {
  //event marketCreated(address[] virtualShareAddresses, address market, uint256 indexed endTime, string description, string extraInfo);//categorical
  event marketCreated(address[2] virtualShareAddresses, address market, uint256 indexed endTime, string description, string extraInfo);//binary
  //event marketCreated(address market, uint256 indexed endTime, string description, string extraInfo, int256 _minPrice, int256 _maxPrice, uint256 _numTicks);//scalar


  function createYesNoMarket(
    uint256 _endTime,
    string memory _description,
    string memory _extraInfo
    ) public payable returns (bool) 

  {
    address[2] memory virtualShareAddresses;
    address newMarket = address(0);
    virtualShareAddresses[0] = address(1);
    virtualShareAddresses[1] = address(2);
    emit marketCreated(virtualShareAddresses, address(newMarket), _endTime, _description, _extraInfo);
    return true;
  }
}
```

In Remix the log is exactly as expected:

```
[
    {
        "from": "0xba8dc1a692093d8abd34e12aa05a4fe691121bb6",
        "topic": "0x723cfaf3d6cd591c1439c0b9b08b74eaa46598df92bd434a707f33f48fa8bbd8",
        "event": "marketCreated",
        "args": {
            "0": [
                "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001",
                "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002"
            ],
            "1": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
            "2": "1575158400",
            "3": "Will it rain on Friday in Sacramento California?",
            "4": "foo",
            "virtualShareAddresses": [
                "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001",
                "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002"
            ],
            "market": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
            "endTime": "1575158400",
            "description": "Will it rain on Friday in Sacramento California?",
            "extraInfo": "foo",
            "length": 5
        }
    }
]
```

With event overloading, there seems to be difficulty interpreting the log:

```
[
    {
        "from": "0x9876e235a87f520c827317a8987c9e1fde804485",
        "data": "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",
        "topics": [
            "0x723cfaf3d6cd591c1439c0b9b08b74eaa46598df92bd434a707f33f48fa8bbd8",
            "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005de30280"
        ]
    }
]
```

Event overloading should work. It can be shown to work if the array element is removed:

```
contract EventTest {
  // event marketCreated(address market, uint256 indexed endTime, string description, string extraInfo);//categorical
  event marketCreated(address market, uint256 indexed endTime, string description, string extraInfo);//binary
  event marketCreated(address market, uint256 indexed endTime, string description, string extraInfo, int256 _minPrice, int256 _maxPrice, uint256 _numTicks);//scalar


  function createYesNoMarket( ...

    emit marketCreated(address(newMarket), _endTime, _description, _extraInfo);
```

That also works as expected:

```
    [
    {
        "from": "0xde6a66562c299052b1cfd24abc1dc639d429e1d6",
        "topic": "0x0d1dda2dfb9ffa94623e4da9d1b79c3d2f94286cf597898c7cb8551e2971b988",
        "event": "marketCreated",
        "args": {
            "0": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
            "1": "1575158400",
            "2": "Will it rain on Friday in Sacramento California?",
            "3": "foo",
            "market": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
            "endTime": "1575158400",
            "description": "Will it rain on Friday in Sacramento California?",
            "extraInfo": "foo",
            "length": 4
        }
    }
]
```

So, even though arrays are okay, and even though event overloading is okay, there does appear to be a problem using those features together. This is possibly a candidate for an issue report, or possibly someone will chime in with a known reason why these features are mutually exclusive.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! I'll file an issue report for this if nobody chimes in in about it the next few days...

Comment: Thanks for voting and accepting. I hope you don't mind. I edited the question title to possibly draw more eyeballs to the interesting issue.

Comment: anything that answers my question is fine by me